# How do you start the Java ME 8.2 Emulator on Linux?

Tags: java, java-me, emulation

I just downloaded and installed the Java ME platform SDK 8.2.  I'm trying to start the emulator and it won't run.  The error is:

```
Java_ME_platform_SDK_8.2/bin $> emulator -Xjam -Xdevice:EmbeddedDevice1

*** Error ***
Failed to connect to device 0!
Reason:
Emulator 0 terminated while waiting for it to register!
```

I'm running on

```
Linux 2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP x86_64 GNU/Linux
CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
```

I'm trying to follow Oracle's [Using the Emulator](https://docs.oracle.com/javame/8.0/sdk-dev-guide/using_emulator.htm) guide, and it doesn't look like it should be difficult.  It looks like should just install the SDK, then run the emulator as I did... it just doesn't work.

I also did the following:

- turned off my firewall
- verified nothing was running on port 1299
- verified my device-manager.object-registry.host=127.0.0.1
- put the /bin directory at the beginning of my path
- set JAVA_HOME to my javamesdk_installdir

The Device Selector UI and the Device Connections Manager UI both start without a problem, and I'm able to see the pre-configured devices, like EmbeddedDevice1.

I also have a plain Java SDK installed on the machine

```
java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)
```